# How to correct PHPstan error link to ObjectManager

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures, phpstan

I have a problem with an error that phpstan brings me up. It's about a load method in a datafixtures.php files. Here is the error :

```
 Parameter #1 $manager (Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager) of method App\AppFixtures\DataFixtures::load() is
         not compatible with parameter #1 $manager (Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager) of method
         Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load().
```

With the following code :

```php
public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $this->updateCompanies();

        $this->loadEventCategories();

        $this->loadEvents();

        $this->loadNotifications();

        $this->manager->flush();

        $this->updateEvent();

        $this->createApiTokens();

        $this->manager->flush();
    }
```

When I tried to ignore the error, it's said that there is no error and right after it brings the same error than above.
So if someone know how to correct the error or ignore ?

Comment: Hi, this looks like a PHPStan bug. Are you on the latest version (0.12.65)?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm on the latest version. But, I found out the problem, it's was just an incorrect use.